# Replace space with underscores python string -

Tags: python, string

```
file = 'file1 data ut.pdf'

print(file)
print(type(file))

'file1 data ut.pdf'
<class 'str'>

file.replace(" ","_")

'_f_i_l_e_1_ _d_a_t_a_ _u_t_._p_d_f'

file.replace("","_")
```

Expected output:

```
file1_data_ut.pdf
```

Comment: I tried `file.replace(" ","_")` and I get the expected output `'file1_data_ut.pdf'`

Comment: Umm...trying to reproduce the issue. I don't get that result, `replace` adds `_` between every letter of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `replace` on your side is not working.

TRY this.

```
file = 'file1 data ut.pdf'


print('_'.join(file.split(' ')))
```

OUTPUT

```
file1_data_ut.pdf
```

---

### Explanation

1. `file`.[`split(' ')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) convert string to list by given operator.

> `['file1', 'data', 'ut.pdf']`

2. `'_'`.[`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) concatenate all the strings in the list and add '_' given string between them.

> `'file1_data_ut.pdf'`

Comment: that worked. can you explain the solution?

Comment: Yeah of course.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain why `file.replace(" ","_")` does not work for you. You can alternatively try this code:

```py
>>> file = 'file1 data ut.pdf'
>>> '_'.join(file.split())
'file1_data_ut.pdf'
```

In essence, [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) returns a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. The default value of `sep` is `' '`. [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.join) returns a string which is the concatenation of the strings in a collection, in this case, the collection is the list generated by `str.split`.

Answer (score -3):

You need to store the updated string in the new variable.

```
file = 'file1 data ut.pdf'

print(file)
print(type(file))

file=file.replace(" ","_")
```